# Load a resource contained in a jar

Tags: java, jar, resources

In my application I load resources in this manner:

```
WinProcessor.class.getResource("repository").toString();
```

and this gives me:

```
file:/root/app/repository   (and I replace "file:" with empty string)
```

This works fine when I run my application from the IDE, but when I run the jar of my application:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

The path becomes:

```
jar:/root/app.jar!/repository
```

is there any way to solve this problem?

I'll use the "repository" dir name in order to create this:

```
ConfigurationContext ctx = (ConfigurationContext) ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(repositoryString, null);
```

In the same manner, I'll get one file name (instead of a dir) and I'll use it this way:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", fileNameString)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It sounds like you're then trying to load the resource using a `FileInputStream` or something like that. Don't do that: instead of calling `getResource`, call [`getResourceAsStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) and read the data from that.

(You could load the resources from the URL instead, but calling `getResourceAsStream` is a bit more convenient.)

EDIT: Having seen your updated answer, it seems other bits of code rely on the data being in a physical single file in the file system. The answer is therefore not to bundle it in a jar file in the first place. You *could* check whether it's in a separate file, and if not extract it to a temporary file, but that's pretty hacky IMO.

Comment: Agree.  Whenever you cannot say with 100% certainty that you will deal with physical single files (java web start for one) you should always code with streams.

Answer (score 8):

When running code using `java -jar app.jar`, java uses ONLY the class path defined in the manifest of the JAR file (i.e. `Class-Path` attribute). If the class is in `app.jar`, or the class is in the class path set in the `Class-Path` attribute of the JAR's manifest, you can load that class using the following code snippet, where the `className` is the fully-qualified class name.

```
final String classAsPath = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
final InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream( path/to/class );
```

Now if the class is not part of the JAR, and it isn't in the manifest's `Class-Path`, then the class loader won't find it. Instead, you can use the `URLClassLoader`, with some care to deal with differences between windows and Unix/Linux/MacOSX.

```
// the class to load
final String classAsPath = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";

// the URL to the `app.jar` file (Windows and Unix/Linux/MacOSX below)
final URL url = new URL( "file", null, "///C:/Users/diffusive/app.jar" );
//final URL url = new URL( "file", null, "/Users/diffusive/app.jar" );

// create the class loader with the JAR file
final URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] { url } );

// grab the resource, through, this time from the `URLClassLoader` object
// rather than from the `ClassLoader` class
final InputStream input = urlClassLoader.getResourceAsStream( classAsPath );
```

In both examples you'll need to deal with the exceptions, and the fact that the input stream is `null` if the resource can't be found. Also, if you need to get the `InputStream` into a `byte[]`, you can use Apache's commons `IOUtils.toByteArray(...)`. And, if you then want a `Class`, you can use the class loader's `defineClass(...)` method, which accepts the `byte[]`.

You can find this code in a [`ClassLoaderUtils`](http://sourceforge.net/p/diffusive/code/ci/5168b7cc7015788bf54b1bddc370c71b144a1762/tree/src/org/microtitan/diffusive/utils/ClassLoaderUtils.java?format=raw) class in the Diffusive source code, which you can find on SourceForge at github.com/robphilipp/diffusive

And a method to create URL for Windows and Unix/Linux/MacOSX from relative and absolute paths in [`RestfulDiffuserManagerResource.createJarClassPath(...)`](https://github.com/robphilipp/diffusive/blob/develop/restful_server/src/main/java/org/microtitan/diffusive/diffuser/restful/resources/RestfulDiffuserManagerResource.java?source=c)

Answer (score 5):

Construct a `URL`, you can then load a resource (even in a jar file) using the [`openStream`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) method.

Comment: That is what `getResourceAsStream` does.