# Link in swt browser to file inside jar file

Tags: html, browser, navigation, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SWT Browser widget: html source inside jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143614/swt-browser-widget-html-source-inside-jar)

I'm loading a page in an SWT browser which is contained in a jar file like so:

```
final Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.FLAT);
browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
browser.setUrl(this.getClass().getResource("/resource/activity.html").toString());
```

So far so good. Now the question is:

1. Is it possible to link **from within** that activity.html page to other pages and images who are contained in the same jar file ?
2. And if so, how ?"

Comment: Not reallly, that question is related to loading the first page in the browser (which already works in this case). The question is, how can you link to other pages after loading the first page.

Comment: well I loaded the activity.html which contains the following html code:
`<html>
  <a href="test.html"></a>
</html>` However when I click it the browser jumps to about:test.hml which is not what I expected. I excepted the browser to jump to the test.html page which is in the same location as the activity.html inside the jar file.