# Opening HTML files in SWT browser from .jar with hyperlinks working

Tags: java, swt, executable-jar

I have a set of help files for my SWT application that I have open in-application using the `Browser` control. Navigation through the help files is done through hyperlinks of relative pathnames (i.e: `<a href="aboutUs.htm">`, so only one html file is actually opened by java code, helpHome.htm. I am opening this using `String homeURL = this.getClass().getResource("/help/helpHome.htm").toString();` and `browser.setURL(homeURL);` This works beautifully when I'm just debugging it in Eclipse. Unfortunately, when I move the project into a .jar, the browser gives the standard "can't find this webpage" error. I've tried using the `browser.setText(String);` function as described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143614/swt-browser-widget-html-source-inside-jar), which works for helpHome.htm, but when I click a hyperlink, it brings me to a blank page displaying the relative pathname. Is there a way to convince browser to open an html file from an executable jar using the `setURL(String)` method? If not, are there any suggested workarounds for me to achieve similar results?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: As long as you're running inside Eclipse, the application is _not_ packaged as a jar file and the files are accessible directly via the file: URL scheme. Once you're using your application via a jar file, then the URL for the browser must refer to a member to a file entry of that jar file. And I highly doubt that the Browser widget understands this scheme...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's kind of what I suspected I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to start an internal Server as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128145/Run-Jetty-Web-Server-Within-Your-Application) on any available port on your application start up and make your html files available as static resources to the server.

Then set the `browser.setURL(homeURL)`. All the subsequent hyperlinks will now point to the server, which knows how to serve the requested resources.

The hyperlinks are resolved to File System Path (Ex. file://C:\workspace....) while you are running or debugging your application in eclipse and things were working fine then. But that is not the case when you run your app from a runnable jar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm working on implementing it now. I'm not sure I understand it completely though. I can't use browser.setURL(homeURL) as of right now because it can't find the page. Unless you have an alternative way to initialize homeURL? Sorry if I'm asking silly questions.

Comment: @connory3 once you start setting up the internal server, you'll automatically come to know what url to set on the `SWTBrowser`