# Show local HTML file with JavaScript in SWT Browser widget in RAP

Tags: swt, eclipse-rap

For my RAP-project I need to show some charts. Because I haven't found any widget for this purpose, my plan was to use the browser widget, so I can use JavaScript-Plugins like Highcharts or Chartsjs. But I can't get it working. If I set an HTML-File in browser.setUrl, the browser widget don't show anything, not even simple HTML. The JavaScript-Console in Chrome says

> Not allowed to load local resource

If I enter the HTML-Code with the `setText` method it shows the HTML, but JavaScript is not working, it don't load external JS-File like the jQuery-library.

Can't this be done this way? Or where is my failure? (Sorry for my bad englisch, I'm not native speaker.)

Here's the Java-Code I tried:

```java
browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
browser.setTouchEnabled(true);
browser.setBounds(10, 10, 358, 200);
browser.setUrl("D:\\STATS\\statistiken.html");
```

Or this:

```java
File file = new File("D:\\STATS\\statistiken.html");
browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
browser.setTouchEnabled(true);
browser.setBounds(10, 10, 358, 200);
browser.setUrl(file.toURI().toString());
```

I tried also some other things, there were not working to.

With HTML in setText-method (I tried external libraries and local libraries in same folder):

```java
browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
browser.setBounds(10, 10, 358, 200);
browser.setText(
    "<html>" +
    "<head>" +
        "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>" +
        "<script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>" +
        "<script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js\"></script>" +
    "</head>" +
    "<body>" +
        "<p>Test</p>" +
        "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>" +
    "</body>" +
    "</htm>");
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local links will not be resolved and external links will not be loaded(Cross Domain problem) in your case.

I could suggest you 2 Solutions.

### Solution 1:

This is useful when you have very few resources(html, javascript, css) to render on `Browser` and no `Hyperlinks`(which when cliked will load a different page).

You can use [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html). Read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html) to start using Velocity.

You can have all the static content in `Velocity Template` and inject Dynamic content into it at Runtime.

Here is the excerpt from one of my Projects.

> **init.vm**

```
 <html dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.transcript {
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
}

.messageBlock {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.message {
    margin-left: 115px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    _white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeChatWindow() { var divT = document.getElementById("divTranscript"); divT.style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - getTopAreaHeight()) + "px"; divT.style.width = (document.body.clientWidth) + "px"; divT.style.overflow = "auto"; divT.style.position = "absolute"; divT.style.left = "0px"; divT.style.top = getTopAreaHeight() + "px";}
 function getTopAreaHeight() { var chatAlert = document.getElementById("chatAlert"); if (chatAlert) { return chatAlert.clientHeight; } return document.getElementById("divBody").clientHeight;}
 isChat=false; window.onresize=resizeChatWindow;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$scriptText
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addChat(chatText){
    $("#divTranscript").append(chatText);

    $("#divTranscript").animate({ scrollTop: $("#divTranscript")[0].scrollHeight }, "slow");

}

</script>
    <body onload="resizeChatWindow();">
        <div id="divBody"></div>
        <div id="divTranscript">$history</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **VelocityUtils**

```
private void init() throws Exception {
    ve = new VelocityEngine();
        Properties velocityProperties = new Properties();
        velocityProperties.put("resource.loader", "class");
        velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.description", "Velocity Classpath Resource Loader");
        velocityProperties.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        ve.init(velocityProperties);
        //ve.init();
}


public String getInitHtml(String history) throws ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException, Exception {
    /* now render the template into a StringWriter */
    StringWriter writer = null;
    /* next, get the Template */
        Template t = ve.getTemplate("templates/init.vm","UTF-8");
        /* create a context and add data */
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        String script = IOUtils.toString(VelocityUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("script/jquery.min.js"), "UTF-8");
        context.put("scriptText", script); //You can even have all the script content in init.vm rather than injecting it at runtime.
        context.put("history", StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(history, StringPool.BLANK));
        writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);
        /* show the World */

    String returnMe = writer.toString();
    return returnMe;
}
```

set the returned `String` in `Browser.setText()`

### Solution 2:

I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099562/opening-html-files-in-swt-browser-from-jar-with-hyperlinks-working/17118012#17118012).

Comment: The Velocity thing is not working. If I got it right, it's just copy the whole jQuery-Code into the document, right? I tried it also the copy and paste way, but this also didn't work. 
I don't know how to set up the jetty server in my project. But Eclipse is starting a server by itself, so why this should change something?

Comment: @ThomasKörner You are right! btw, what do you mean by not working?  Are you facing any issues with `Velocity`? Did you try to view the html source in the browser and see what you are expecting? When scripts worked for me using `Velocity` why dont it work for you? If you can't run simple `Jetty` server following the tutorial then I'm of no help to you. Thank you!!

Comment: Velocity is working correct! But the JavaScript-Code inside the init.vm is not working. But with Browser#evaluate it's working now! So thank you very much!!!

Comment: For others with the same question: I also needed to put the JS-Files in the same package where VelocityUtils is located.