# Resource loading in Java not working as it should

Tags: java, resources, jar

This is the well known problem of loading resources from a jar file. This is not the first time I've tried to do this, but now it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

Normally I try to load the Resources with `this.getClass.getResource("foo.png")`, or `getResourceAsStream()`and it works. Now however it does not. The Resource is always null.

If I let `System.out.println(this.getClass.getResource(""))` print me the path (from eclipse) it shows `/path/to/eclipseproject/package/structure/`. Running this from a jar it just shows `rsrc:package/structure`

If I recall correctly this should print the path to the jar. Furthermore I thought this would print the package structure in both cases. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the thing...

When Extracting the file from the Jar use:

```
this.getClass.getResource("/foo.png")
```

When running from a runnable Jar use, to reference an external file in the Jar folder path:

```
this.getClass.getResource("foo.png")
// When running this from Eclipse, it would refer to files in project root!
```

I have a code in the lower level determining where I'm running from to determine the correct path.

Comment: thanks. This workes. I accidentally checked `package required libraries into generated Jar`, that caused the Resource to say `rsrc`

Answer (score 0):

Doe this get the path you need?

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("<your class name>.class").getPath();
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file) for more on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you prepend the path to the resources with '/', Class.getResource() will search for the resource in class package. E.g.: tld.domain.Foo.class.getResource("Bar.txt") will search for tld/domain/Bar.txt

Answer (score 0):

Check the URLClassLoader for all the gory details, but it really depends on whether you are trying to access a ressource in the jar,

- using a class loaded inside the same jar, in this case your file 'root' is the root of the jar
- using a class loaded outside the jar (your eclipse case) where the root is your 'working directory'

To access resources inside a jar from outside, you should use something like

`URL url = new URL( "jar", "", "file:" + jar.getCanonicalPath(  ) + "!/" + localPathResource );`
`url.openStream(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13772759/1886883) provides an explanation of how to load class resources from JAR files, even when the class is not in the JAR file and not in the `Class-Path` specified in the JAR file's manifest. There are also links to code.