# The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: java, jar, path, zip, executable-jar

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: town.zip (The system cannot find the f
ile specified)
```

When I try to load my 3d scene on `Windows 7` from a JAR that was built on `Linux` and vice versa `Linux` gets the same error as the JAR was packages on `Windows`. I use just the normal settings for creating a *runnable* jar in `eclipse`. What am I doing wrong? This seems to have little or nothing to do with my actual code and is just a packing question.

The code that is loading the file, which works on the same platform on which it is built, is:

`assetManager.registerLocator("town.zip", ZipLocator.class);`

and this works when the project is run from eclipse or on the same platform as which it is built.

Comment: is this file supposed to be inside your jar or alongside it?

Comment: It's supposed to be inside the jar and when I run it on the build platform it is OK. It is only between platforms it won't work which is confusing. Opening the Jar file I cannot find the file town.zip and adding it into the jar won't help either.

Comment: If it's inside a jar you have to load it as a resource instead of a file. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/java-load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar) answer for some tips.

Comment: Show code that loads the file.

Comment: @Thomas But I'm loading it exactly the way from the example and it works when the JAR is run on the same platform as which it is built. There must be some config in eclipse how to package the thing.

Comment: @Strelok I put the load code in the question now. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what frameworks you're using, but a quick Google search pointed that you're using the `jmonkeyengine`, it looks like the `ZipLocator` actually loads the files using `new File(...)`, so your `town.zip` should actually sit alongside your JAR file and not packaged inside it.