# Error with running the .Jar file

Tags: java

The program work fine in eclipse, and I want to make it into an executable, so the user can just click on the exe file. But first i have to make it into a .jar. But it would not run in the .jar file, i try it in the terminal and it gives me this error, im not sure what the errors are because the program runs fine in eclipse.

the errors are

```
C:\User\Mondi\Desktop\exe>java -jar RunGUI.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: airport.txt <??????????>
      at java.io.FileInputStream.open<Native Method>
      at java.io.FileInputStrem.<init><unknown source>
      at java.util.scanner.<init><unknown source>
      at dijkstra.FileProcess.loadtegMap<FileProcess.java:51>
      at dijkstra.RunGUI.main<RunGUI.java:13>
```

Comment: According to that trace, it can't find the file "airport.txt."

Comment: so you have airport.txt stuffed in jar?

Comment: Look here, perhaps it'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar

Comment: i have actually tried to put the .txt file in every folder i can within the package but still gives me the same error...

Comment: Its looking for the file in *current directory*, do you have it in `C:\User\Mondi\Desktop\exe`? If it's in the jar, you need to load it as a resource like @iluxa says

Comment: @MiserableVariable Oh, so it has to be in the current directory, it WORKS now, i thought it just has to be inside the .jar file...THANK YOU SO MUCH for all of your answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, the file has to be in *current directory* for the code as written to find it.

Is that how you want it to be? If `airport.txt` is a fixed file the perhaps you should add it in the jar along with the compiled code. If it is in the root directory of the jar, you would use `getResourceAsStream`, which you can then wrap in a `Scanner`

Comment: i will just stay with what i have got now, its working now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open the airport.txt file with no path, it will look for it in the working directory - which is not a directory inside the jar.

You need to look into getResourceAsStream in order to read a file in a jar.