# Create executable JAR from classes and images using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, deployment, executable-jar

I have the following folder:

```
Game Of Life
|_bin
| |_Board.class
| |_Frame.class (main class)
|   ...
|_res
| |_playToolbar.png
| |_pauseToolbar.png
|   ...
|_src
  |_Board.java
  |_Frame.java
    ...
```

How do I create an executable `.jar` containing every class and image, so that when I execute the `.jar` it runs the `Frame` class? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: do you use an IDE? eclipse for instance provides excellent tools for that

Comment: What type of project is it? ANT, Maven, etc.

Comment: @Simiil the problem with using an IDE is that anyone wishing to improve upon that code has to have the IDE... Build tools are a better choice

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse. @Simiil

Comment: @fhe while I agree, with Netbeans at least, the move towards Maven is making that a lesser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to put your pictures inside a package. This way, everything will be packaged and loaded from your JAR file.

Afterward you will have to load your images using the getResource(...) method from an instance of Class.

You will have something like this:

```
GameOfLife
|- src
|  |- my
|  |  |- company
|  |  |  |- app
|  |  |  |  | Board.java
|  |  |  |  | Frame.java
|  |  |  |  |- resources
|  |  |  |  |  |- playToolbar.png
|  |  |  |  |  |- pauseToolbar.png
```

Then to create an ImageIcon of "playToolbar.png" from the Frame class you will have to use:

```
new ImageIcon(Frame.class.getResource("resources/playToolbar.png"));
```

Or:

```
new ImageIcon(Frame.class.getResource("/my/company/app/resources/playToolbar.png"));
```

If you are using Netbeans GUI builder, it can load resources from package without any problem.

To autorun your Frame class you have to create a MANIFEST.MF file and put it inside a folder named META-INF at the root of your JAR. Inside, you can define Frame as the Main-Class:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: my.company.app.Frame
```

Eclipse can do this step automatically if you select export->Runnable Jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can do a `Rightclick->Export` on the project and select `Runnable Jar File` under `Java`. Your `res` folder has to be configured as a source Folder in eclipse, otherwise it wont be exported.

You also have to regard that Loading the images may be different once they are packed in a jar file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar) for more information