# Read a file, which is included inside a jar

Tags: java, jar, path, embedded-resource, readfile

I have a jar file, say **archive1.jar**, resides in **/home/ext/libs**. This has a couple of classes, and also a text file (**data.txt**) at the root of the hierarchy of the jar. One of the classes of this jar (say **Data.java**) reads the file to initiate some internal data structure.

Now, the archive1.jar is included as a library of another program, called **Parsing**, which is executed in a completely different directory **/home/progs** (archive1.jar is specified in the classpath of the execution command of the program).

The problem I am facing is that now Data.java cannot understand the path of data.txt anymore, because it assumes that data.txt resides in **/home/progs** instead of being inside archive1.jar in **/home/ext/libs**.

My question is what change should I make inside **Data.java** in order for it to understand that the **data.txt** is inside the archive1.jar? In short, how to make Data.java be able to read data.txt inside archive1.jar, no matter where the calling program is.

**Note:** In thread **Java resource as file**, thing was a bit different, and also there was no answer to how to read the file inside the jar. One said it might be impossible.

Comment: could we see some code?

Comment: I looked into "Java resources as file" thread but did not really find an adequate answer. Here is the code. Inside Data.java, there is BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt")); This Data.java is inside archive1.jar, which in turn is in /home/ext/libs

Comment: How can you not find an adequate answer when that Q (and things that are dups of it) tell you exactly what to do, and you're not doing it, at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar
I think what you're looking for is getResourceAsStream.

Comment: `java -cp  archive1.jar;other.jar our.com.Main`  Either that or specify by relative path in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to access resource files inside `JAR` archives is by using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` . Using this ensures that the resource is loaded from the archive not from the filesystem. For example if you have `data.txt` in the same location as `Data.java` within the `JAR` archive, then you would access the `data.txt` in this way

```
InputStream is=getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.txt");
```

Once you have got an `InputStream` to the resource proceed with the way you like.