# Exporting to a exe with jarsplice

Tags: java, jar, export, exe, lwjgl

I am making a game using lwjgl, and am trying to figure out how to export it into a single runnable jar or exe.

I saw that i can use jarsplice to make exe's fairly easily so i followed the instructions,

1. I exported a jar from eclipse(not a runnable)
2. Then added that jar, all the jars the game uses, and the natives it needs.
3. When i try to create an exe in jarsplice, it says error opening zip file.

I am pretty sure that when eclipse makes a jar it packages all the folders in the project into it as zip folders.

So should i have eclipse make a jar with only the classes and not the resource folder, then use that with jarsplice?

And if so where would i have to put that folder and not have it accessible by end users?

Comment: Well obviously i don't mean not possible to reach at all, i just mean i want all the files in one single icon, and not have the folders just sitting there, you could just help me out... not antagonize...

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me:

1. Export as Runnable Jar with Eclipse selecting "Copy required libraries into sub-folder next to generated JAR". This folder is called `[jarname]_lib`.
2. Open JarSplice and add the main program jar, and all of the libraries that can be found in the `[jarname]_lib`.
3. Add all of the natives for the project, these can be found in the `[jarname]_lib/natives` folder.
4. Add the main class location
5. Export Jar

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe you can try running it before putting it through JarSplice.

Comment: If the problem only happens when using Jarsplice, then maybe take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar